# There is some css trick to correct errors depending on the browser?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I want to fix some errors on CSS displayed on Google Chrome and Safari, however Firefox and Opera mobil are showing correct. Few years ago a find that writting some code for example inside ie7.css the Internet Explorer 7 read the lines and the bug can be solved.

Now I have an issue with chrome and androind navigator, So I think if the bug can be solved on Chrome the bug will be fixed on andriod tablets.

for example I have a line:

```
.logo-social { position:relative; padding: 10px 0; margin-top:-10px; z-index:500; }
```

On Firefox my social bars appears -10px above the menu and Slider, buy On chrome appears 20px below the menu and slider, So I set **z-index:500;** to display over slider and not behind.

If I set **margin-top:-25px** the social bar will be displayed correctly on Chrome buy looks out of place under firefox. :/

If there are something to fix like IE7 or IE8 will be great!

Comment: From my point of view, a decent css reset and a valid coding renders quite identical for most browsers except for some form elements like input[type=text] or select. Did you validate your code ?

Answer (score 1):

use the media query technique

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 

/* webkit specific rules here */

Body {}

}
```

this will target the webkit browsers, or you can use javascript

Answer (score 1):

**CSS Solution**

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
 // your css here for .logo-social
}
```

Note: But that will include opera also as it also uses webkit now.

**Javascript solution**

```
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Chrome/") != -1 || navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Safari/") != -1) {
// modify  
}
```

Make sure you run the command on specific browser to cross check the appVersion returned